# Add button to Android Widget dynamically

Tags: android, android-widget

I wan't to add `button` to android `widget` dynamically.
I've tried to do it by following way from main `Activty`:

> ```
>   Button a = new Button(this);
>   a.setText("Pushme");
>   RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.llay);
>   rl.addView(a);
> ```

`RelativeLayout` here it's `widget` layout.

From `AppWidgetProvider` custom class I cant do it too, cause I'm unable to create there button.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`addView()` on a `RemoteViews`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#addView%28int,%20android.widget.RemoteViews%29) to add a nested `RemoteViews`.

Or, define all your buttons in your base layout that you use with `RemoteViews`, with some buttons initially set to `android:visibility="gone"`. Then, [use `setViewVisibility()` on the `RemoteViews`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setViewVisibility%28int,%20int%29) to make them visible as desired.

Comment: But I wan't to generate button in runtime is it possible?

Comment: @Pepelac: I believe that I covered this in my answer. Note that what you want may not work very well, as the app widget's overall size will not change, and so your added button may cause other things in your app widget to shrink.